# Delphi 5 : Total number of page in pdf

Tags: delphi, pdf, pdf-parsing

I am maintaining an old application that is built with Delphi 5.
I need to determine the total number of pages in a given pdf file.

I guess I could translate any solution for plain C also.

The current solution I have is forking a pdftk process, and parse its output. But this is quite slow, so I was wondering if I could find a good open-source pdf parser library for delphi (5...)... And it seems it doesn't exist.

So I tried to implement things like looking into the file's raw content for occurences of "/Type /Page" or "/Count" or "Linearized ... /N". But none of these -nor a combination of them- work in every case.

So I wondered if I could find an open-source DLL that I could make use of from Delphi 5. But I couldn't find any neither. I stumbled upon iTextSharp but it is for .NET and I don't understand howto use it in a plain delphi5 program...

So my final thought is this : is there any change I could find the source code for -say- pdftk and compile it as a DLL? Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Is there any solution I am missing?

I thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have Adobe Acrobat installed on the machine?

Comment: Have you already checked this [PDF Page Count Algorithm](http://angusj.com/delphitips/pdfpagecount.php) ?

Comment: @MartynA : At least Adobe Acrobat Reader is installed, yes.

Comment: Well, with the full Acrobat, you can use automation to load your Pdf into it and manipulate it in code the way you can in Acrobat using its GUI.  Getting the page count is trivial.   It's a while since I used automation with Acrobat Reader.  You might try importing its type library into Delphi and have a look -  I certainly used it with D5 about 10 years ago.

Comment: @fantaghirocco I just tried your source code that looked pretty exactly what I was looking for. BUT I get the same wrong page numbers that I got with my own implementation... For example, I have a LINEARIZED pdf that mentions  <<...LINEARIZED .... /N 4..... but that displays only 3 pages in the end (I suspect partial updates that override the root /Pages...). Your code says 4 pages.

Comment: @MartinA : I don't want GUI interaction. Does adobe automation work for console applications?

Comment: I have never tried automating acrobat from a console app, but can't immediately see why it wouldn't work - you certainly don't need the Acrobat gui on-screen to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the [PDFLib dll](http://www.pdflib.com/)?

It is a very efficient library, and they have binding for Delphi, either via COM or via their dll. I guess you could use Delphi 5 with this library.

Comment: I have not tried it yet because I understand it is not free for use in a commercial application... (?)

Comment: @user5334551 Yes, it is not free, but it is probably the best pdf library out there. And iText/iTextSharp are NOT free either in a commercial application.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run the free `pdfinfo` tool?

Download it from http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf

It returns such information:

```
Title:          Optimizing software in C++
Keywords:       software C++ optimization compiler
Author:         Agner Fog
Creator:        Microsoft® Word 2013
Producer:       Microsoft® Word 2013
CreationDate:   12/15/14 14:25:13
ModDate:        12/15/14 14:25:13
Tagged:         yes
Form:           none
Pages:          37
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.32 x 841.92 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      531693 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

So here you have your number of pages.
And it is very fast.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks! Actually the current solution is forking an exe already (pdftk). I may try to compare with xpdf but I guess that the heaviness/slowlyness is because of the new process creation rather than the execution of it... am I wrong?

Comment: Some quick tests show that in my case xpdf seems faster than pdftk (an average 150ms again 250ms for pdftk). That's a good start, but I was more looking for some way to avoid the heaviness of creation a new process... Do you think it would be complicated to modify the sources and build a DLL instead of an exe? Again, I thank you anyway :)

Comment: @user5334551 If it was of any help, please vote or upvote the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you install adobe acrobat (not reader) on user's PC then you can use OLE automation.

Here example how to open file and read pages count:

```
    uses
      ComObj, ActiveX;

    function TmyForm.IsOLEObjectInstalled(Name: String): Boolean;
    var
      ClassID: TCLSID;
      Rez: HRESULT;
    begin
      Rez := CLSIDFromProgID(PWideChar(WideString(Name)), ClassID);

      Result := (Rez = S_OK);
    end;

    procedure TmyForm.ButtonCheckPagesClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      doc: OleVariant;
      pagesCount: Integer;
    begin
      if IsOLEObjectInstalled('AcroExch.PDDoc') then
      begin
        doc := CreateOleObject('AcroExch.PDDoc');

        if doc.Open('C:\test\test.pdf') then
        begin
          pagesCount := doc.GetNumPages;
          ShowMessageFmt('pages count = %d', [pagesCount]);
        end
        else
        begin
          ShowMessage('Can''t open file');
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        ShowMessage('You must install adobe acrobat for that feature');
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Sadly, this application is deployed onto thousands of computers - paying for Acrobat's license is no option... Thank you for taking the time to answer anyway!